# Bootstrap 3 - Having a column the height of 2 rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do a layout where a column is the height of two rows.  I can't seem to as the correct question to find previous answers.

I am using Bootstrap 3.

Here is the code

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="margin:100px">
        <!---spacer-->
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12" id="top-row"></div>
    <div>

    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12" id="bottom-row"></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm 12" id="quote-2-high"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="margin:100px">
    <!---spacer-->
</div>

</div> <!-- extra closing div ? -->
```

And some CSS

```
#top-row {
  background-color: lime;
  height: 250px;
}

#bottom-row {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 250px;
}

#quote-2-high {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 500px;
}
```

I have a codepen here if it is of any use. http://codepen.io/steeth/pen/gPVwMK?editors=1100

As you can see the blue column starts at the top of the red, but I want to to start at the top of the green.

Comment: start at the top of the green you mean ?

Comment: @DavidH. - yes sorry. Will edit.

Comment: Codepen is now broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <div class="row" id="top-row"></div>
            <div class="row" id="bottom-row"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" id="quote-2-high"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The [Bootstrap Grid System](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) it is a very simple concept, but I recommend you to use this tool, it will help you so much: http://shoelace.io/

---

[image: how to add column]

Comment: Thanks for your help - this works! And so simple too . . .

Comment: @SteveDavies Glad to help you.

Comment: How do yo use shoelace.io? It looks like I can only add columns?

Comment: @SteveDavies see the screenshot above.

Comment: The penny has dropped, I can put divs into the columns once I have got the layout in a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

**UPADATE:**
Using this markup the blue box will stay as one box instead of two seperating one. The pink box gets move up for 250px and so is under the green box.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12" id="top-row"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm 12" id="quote-2-high"></div>        
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12" id="bottom-row"></div>
</div>

#bottom-row {
  background-color: pink;
  margin-top: -250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

You need to use a completly different markup.

In each row there is place for columns with the summed up with of 12, so you go ahead and place a 8 and 4 in the first row and another 8 and 4 in the second row.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12" id="top-row"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm 12" id="quote-2-high"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12" id="bottom-row"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm 12" id="quote-2-high"></div>
</div>
```

Remove the double height on your blue element and you're done:

```
#top-row {
  background-color: lime;
  height: 250px;
}

#bottom-row {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 250px;
}

#quote-2-high {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 250px;
}
```

Demo: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/chimmer/pen/NxQbjN)

Comment: Thanks for your help it's not quite what I am after - I need the aqua area to be a whole box rather than two separate - in a smaller device the box is separated, and I still need it to be one.  Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Well that's no problem either, but a little hackish, Pen updated, see answer in a second.