# Bootstrap 3.3 - multi row for one div

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'am learning Bootstrap and after some search on stackoverflow i would like to know if it's possible to get a div col into multiple row easily.

here is what i've done so far :

HTML :

```
<html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <title>testing</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">1st level with 12 col
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">2nd level with 8 col
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">3rd level with 4 col</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">3rd level with 6 col
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">4th level with 3 col</div>
              <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">4th level with 5 colonnes</div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">2nd level with 4 col</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.container -->
  <script src="js/boostrap.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
body{
  padding-top: 10px;
}

[class*="col-"], footer{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/*--------------------------------------- Responsive ---------------------------------------*/

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

and i've got this : 
[image: result of the code bellow]

i would like to understand why the 3rd level with 6 col, 4th level with 3col andthe 4th level with 5 col are displayed in two rows and how i could reproduce this to integrate a psd. ( For example get a div with 3col and 4rows)

Thanks you

EDIT : Answer :

Here is what i've understand, if i want to have multiple a col with multiple row i have to subdivise my template like this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <div class="row" id="top-row"></div>
            <div class="row" id="bottom-row"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" id="quote-2-high"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in one row i make two div, each in separate row, to have the main div sized with two row.
Thanks to Jeremy, and Mustapha Aoussar i know right now how to use this and i also know that there is an usefull tools who can help me to see clearly the bootstrap's grid system : http://shoelace.io/

Comment: A row has 12 cols, so a div with col-6 is half of his row. So the "4th level with 3 col" div is 1/4th of his row (3/12 = 1/4th).

Comment: okay, seems logic, but i don't understand how i can reproduce this behavior. If i want to have multiple row into a div col, i have to fill it with stuff to get more rows. There is a cleaner way to do that ? What i have to do to get an empty div col with more than a row ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579058/bootstrap-3-having-a-column-the-height-of-2-rows Take a look at this link

Comment: thank you for the answer, i'll edit my question for answering !